# Why do I get only the last object of an array in my Java code?

Tags: java

I don't understand why only the last object **water** of array **drinksRange** is shown after executing the code even if the value of **moneyAmount** is 150 or more

```
 public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Coffee-machine");

    Drink[] drinksRange = new Drink [4];

    drinksRange[0] = new Drink(Drink.name = "cappuccino", Drink.price = 150);
    drinksRange[1] = new Drink(Drink.name = "espresso", Drink.price = 80);
    drinksRange[2] = new Drink(Drink.name = "milk", Drink.price = 50);
    drinksRange[3] = new Drink(Drink.name = "water", Drink.price = 20);

    System.out.print("Insert money: ");
    int moneyAmount = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

        for (Drink i : drinksRange) {
            if (moneyAmount >= i.price) {
                System.out.println("You can buy " + i.name);
            }
        }
}

public class Drink {
  static String name;
  static int price;

 public Drink (String drinkName, int drinkPrice) {
  name = drinkName;
  price = drinkPrice;
  System.out.println(name + " - " + price);
 }
}
```

As a result I get this:

```
Coffee-machine
cappuccino - 150
espresso - 80
milk - 50
water - 20
Insert money: 150
You can buy water
You can buy water
You can buy water
You can buy water
```

Comment: Not sure how it even compiles, considering you are missing an `}` for your main method.

Comment: Read up on what `static` means

Comment: You have `static int price;` Static means that this variable belongs to Class, not to Instance. So it changes every time to new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fields

```java
static String name;
static int price;
```

are **`static`** hence the last value will be the final value for all objects when u are calling Drink.[any static property] hence the arraylist only contains the drink as water and value 20.

Check the modified code below:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SOTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Coffee-machine");

        Drink[] drinksRange = new Drink [4];

        drinksRange[0] = new Drink("cappuccino", 150);
        drinksRange[1] = new Drink("espresso",80);
        drinksRange[2] = new Drink("milk", 50);
        drinksRange[3] = new Drink("water", 20);

        System.out.print("Insert money: ");
        int moneyAmount = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

        for (Drink i : drinksRange) {
            if (moneyAmount >= i.price) {
                System.out.println("You can buy " + i.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
class Drink {
    String name;
    int price;

    public Drink (String drinkName, int drinkPrice) {
        name = drinkName;
        price = drinkPrice;
        System.out.println(name + " - " + price);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Coffee-machine
cappuccino - 150
espresso - 80
milk - 50
water - 20
Insert money: 200
You can buy cappuccino
You can buy espresso
You can buy milk
You can buy water
```

Answer (score 1):

`static int price` this is causing that bug
whenever you write a `static` keyword it means there's only one copy of it. So the `lastest` value is picked which in your case is `Drink.price = 20`
eg.

```
Line 1    drinksRange[0] = new Drink(Drink.name = "cappuccino", Drink.price = 150)
Line 2    drinksRange[1] = new Drink(Drink.name = "espresso", Drink.price = 80)
Line 3    drinksRange[2] = new Drink(Drink.name = "milk", Drink.price = 50)
Line 4    drinksRange[3] = new Drink(Drink.name = "water", Drink.price = 20)
```

No doubt this makes an instance of `Drink`, So line 1 when executed `drinksRange[0]` has its own space in memory but the `members` in the class `static String name, static int price` have independent memory in `heap`
so when line 1 is executed  `name` as `cappuccino` and `price` as `150`
when line 2 is executed `name` as `espresso` and `price` as `80`
when Line 3 is executed `name` as `milk` and `price` as `50`
when line 4 is executed `name` as `water` and `price` as `20`

So in order to have the output, you wanted just remove that `static` keyword and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The static variable gets memory only once in the class area at the time of class loading.

```
static String name;
static int price;
```

In your case you can't put it in your code it will take the last value "water" you have on your array

Put it like this then it will work correctly :)

```
String name;
int price;
```